# Spring: complex object creation

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, assisted-inject

I've tried to create a complex object by using spring's `@Autowired` annotation but it looks like it is not possible.

I'm trying to create two objects: `View` and `Presenter`, with `prototype` scopes and then inject their references to each other. What is more: I'd like to pass two additional parameters from the creator of the instance and inject some additional services from the IoC container.

In Guice it is possible via "assisted injection", but how can I achieve that in spring?

Comment: See Java and XML based config in Spring. `@Autowired` cannot be used for complex configurations.

Comment: What is your problem? it should work. Of course you need to attach the @Autowired annotation to the files (or setter) and not to the constructor.

Comment: @Ralph No, it shouldn't.

Comment: And why not? -- It seams that I do not understand your scenario.

Comment: @Ralph Because circular dependencies with `@Autowired` generally works only for `Singleton` scope. In my case objects have `prototype` scope.

Comment: @Gregory: i can not find any hint for `prototype` scope in your question. May you should impove you question with the relevant details!